# Props data getting updated on Button click in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The following is my component where the props data getting updated when the searchItem() has been executed. I can't understand why this is happening.
How can I fix this issue?

```
const DefaultTabGroup = ({data}) => {

const [res , setRes] = useState({});

useEffect(() =>{
   setRes(data);
},[data]);


const searchItem = () =>{
    let transData = [];
    res.map((d) =>{
       let a = d;
       a.connectors = [];
       transData.push(a);
    });
};

//code.....

}
export default DefaultTabGroup;
```

Comment: because data is a reference
So when you make setRes(data), res === data, they are the same reference.
If you want to avoid that, you can make the following : 
setRes({...data})

Answer (score 0):

You should not change/mutate the state directly in React ([Here is an answer in stackoverflow about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40309023/12252478)).

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const DefaultTabGroup = ({ data }) => {
  const [res, setRes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRes(data);
  }, [data]);

  const searchItem = () => {
    const transData = res.map((d) => {
      const a = { ...d }; // Create a copy of the object
      a.connectors = []; // Modify the copied object
      return a;
    });

    // code ...
    setRes(transData);
  };
};

export default DefaultTabGroup;
```

You should create a new array "transData" and update the state with that.